# Want html code to diaply a message as warning, but i dont want it displayed in a seperate box and neither do i want any buttons to be displayed

Tags: css, html

I have to add a message to show the user that he has made some changes but i do not want it in a seperate box. I have a summary page in which i want to add this info, but i want to make sure that the reader sees it. SO i want the message in a yellow background, and a warning image with it, and no button. I dont want it as a box, i just want it as a plain message without any buttons and i want to add it add the end of my summary-view. Please tell me the html and css code to use for it. Or if there's any option with which i can make an advanced component thats displayed like this and i can just render that component.

Comment: Is there anything that you have tried out so far?

Comment: SHow your html/css please that you've tried to use already.

Comment: No. i am new to html and css and have this use case requirement. I have attached the image also.

Comment: @RinieSingh where is image .......

Comment: Oh i am not able to post it coz of restrictions by stackoverflow. Can u let me know how to write inline warning messages, i think it should work that way

Comment: Rohit cannot post the image. Sorry.

Comment: “i am new to html and css and have this use case requirement.” — Fair enough, but Stack Overflow isn’t designed to provide you with HTML and CSS training, or to do your job for you. You need to have a go yourself and then ask specific questions about the code you’ve written, or make your question more specific (e.g. “Which HTML element would be most appropriate for a notification message?”, “How do I give an HTML element a background colour?”)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use HTML5 validations

for an example:

```
Your Name: <input type="text" name="name" required>
```

or

you can use javascript/jquery validations.

if you want to use success,warning and error message you need to use server side languages such as php, java or c#

for the styling you can check this [link](http://css.dzone.com/news/css-message-boxes-different-me)

Answer (score 0):

HTML doesn’t have an element specifically designed for user notifications.

In HTML5, you might want to put the notification in [a `<section>` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-author-20110809/the-section-element.html#the-section-element). In HTML 4, you’d probably just use a `<div>`.

You could wrap the contents in an `<em>` or `<strong>` tag, as they convey emphasis, and notifications are meant to attract the user’s attention.